# How can I set validation in this case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

title is not required field.
I only want to validate when it's not nil(only when the user typed something in)

```
validates_format_of :title, :with => /\A[A-Za-z0-9_]+\z/, :message => "must be half-width English numbers and letters, and_"
```

However, once I set this, title field became required field.
How can I set it up that it validates only when title field is not nil???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
validates_format_of :title, :with => /\A[A-Za-z0-9_]+\z/, :message => "must be half-width English numbers and letters, and_", :if => lambda{ !self.title.nil? }
```

Comment: Thanks so much:) It's perfect answer! I'll check it as answered within 8 mins

Comment: Glad to be of assistance :-)